# How to upload Vue project on namecheap server

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, namecheap

i'm tying yo host vue webaplication on namecheap hosting. when i install i open it in console has error Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Comment: what are you uploading? the whole project folder?

Comment: yes in to public_html folder

Comment: I do still recommend using a git-based workflow overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install a vue project you need to compile it to production. First go to your project and open a terminal, then type `npm run build`

Vue will build your project for production and leave the result into your dist folder. Then you can upload only the contents of the dist folder into your server

[image]

Comment: i have build it

Comment: not it has error in console Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
server

Comment: in localhost it works but not on sertver

Comment: But you cannot upload the whole project. You need to upload only the dist folder

Comment: how thats posiible ? i have to add all main folders into dist ?

Comment: i only upload dist file and it runs thank you

Comment: you are welcome. If this answers your question please mark it as such clicking on the green check you see at the left of the answer